# Как получить объект связанный через GenericForeignKey

Tags: python, django

Предположим у меня есть такие модели:

```
class FirstType(models.Model):
    pass

class SecondType(models.Model):
    pass

class Comment(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Затем создаю экземпляр класса Comment, ссылающийся на FirstType.

Как мне через объект **FirstType** получить все **Comment** связанный с ним через **GenericForeignKey**?

*Comment не должен быть связан напрямую с FirstType и SecondType

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того какая стоит перед вами задача.

1. Если вам нужен queryset, то используйте select_related()
   https://django.fun/tutorials/select_related-i-prefetch_related-v-django/

   queryset = FirstType.objects.select_related('content_type').all()
2. Если в шаблоне HTML `{% for _ in firsttype.comment_set.all %}`

Answer (score 0):

На утро нашел ответ на свой вопрос в документации.
Нужно использовать поле **GenericRelation** в моделях на которые ссылается **GenericForeignKey**

```
class FirstType(models.Model):
    comments = GenericRelation('Comment')

class SecondType(models.Model):
    comments = GenericRelation('Comment')
```

Далее пользоваться полем *comments* как обычным queryset